# TPC inheritance throws an exception on inserts

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In a database I have `Reservations` and `OldReservations` tables, where `OldReservations` is a copy ( of `Reservations` table ) and is used to store old reservations. Both tables use autogenerated identity keys, but first has a seed of 0 and second has a seed of 1000, so key values in the two tables don't overlap. Here are the steps I did to create TPC inheritance:

1) I derived `OldReservation` entity from `Reservation` entity
2) I removed the overlapping properties from `OldReservation` entity
3) I've then mapped the `OldReservations` table fields in the XML of the EDMX file:

```
      <EntitySetMapping Name="Reservations">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(BAModel.Reservation)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Reservations">
            <ScalarProperty Name="ReservationID" ColumnName="ReservationID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ReservationDate" ColumnName="ReservationDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="EventID" ColumnName="EventID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ContactID" ColumnName="ContactID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="RowVersion" ColumnName="RowVersion" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(BAModel.OldReservation)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="OldReservations">
            <ScalarProperty Name="ReservationID" ColumnName="ReservationID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ReservationDate" ColumnName="ReservationDate" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="EventID" ColumnName="EventID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ContactID" ColumnName="ContactID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="RowVersion" ColumnName="RowVersion" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
```

After I do the above steps the project compiles without any errors, but when I try to insert a new row into `OldReservations` table I get:

*UpdateException: A value shared across entities or associations is generated in more than one location. Check that mapping does not split an EntityKey to multiple store-generated columns. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.*

```
        var reservation = new OldReservation();
        reservation.ReservationDate = DateTime.Now;
        reservation.ContactID = 129;

        context.Reservations.AddObject(reservation);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

This exception is thrown before EF manages to send insert command to the database. Any ideas why I'm getting the exception?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have auto-generated `ReservationID` in your database tables? How is autogeneration defined? Also what other operations did you done on the context instance used to save `OldReservation` (loading or storing other `Reservation` and `OldReservation` instances)?

Comment: Uh, I didn't notice your reply before. Yes, tables use autogenerated keys ( Reservations has seed of 0 and OldReservations has seed of 1000 ). I'm not sure what you mean what other operations I have done on the context instance?! If you mean in code, then I didn't do anything beside creating a new OldReservation entity and trying to insert it into OldReservations table

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this exception because you're using 'IsTypeOf(BAModel.Reservation)' instead of just 'BAModel.Reservation'. Because of this not just BAModel.Reservation but also types derived from BAModel.Reservation are mapped to the Reservations Table. So what happens is that an OldReservation is mapped to the Reservations Table and the OldReservations Table.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is true, since even if I replace ( in MSL ) entry "TypeName=IsTypeOf(BAModel.OldReservation)" with "TypeName=BAModel.OldReservation" I still get same exception ( I'm not able to replace "TypeName=IsTypeOf(BAModel.Reservation)" with "TypeName=BAModel.Reservation", since I get an exception ).